# How to get index of command line arguments passed when process was launched?

Tags: node.js, minimist

For example:
`node app.js --help --path=asd`

I want to know index of `--help` argument to be sure that it a first.

Minimist returns an object which keys are these arguments, but we cann't be sure of the order of the keys of the object.

I see only one solution:

```
if (process.argv[2].indexOf('--help') === 0 || process.argv[2].indexOf('-h') === 0 ) {...}
```

Comment: Your solution seems good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no ready-made solution, so:

```
if (process.argv[2].indexOf('--help') === 0 || process.argv[2].indexOf('-h') === 0 ) {...}
```